# div not adjusting height when loading with ajax

Tags: jquery, height, responsive-design

So...

I want to create a fully responsive website in which we recommend the best mobile apps. I have the apps in a json string and load it through jquery using the $.ajax method into a content div (actually a section, using HTML5).

```
<section id="content-wrapper" class="colums cols-12">
    <section id="content" class="gratisapps centered clearfix cols-12">
    </section>
</section>
```

To make this website responsive (first 960px fixed width, for smaller screens I want to use a fluid layout), I've used the 12-colum grid. The header and footer scale along with the browser width, but the content doesn't. I believe it has something to do with the fact that my content container has no height, though all the apps are loaded in it.

```
var _gratisApps;
function inladenApplicaties(){
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"JSON",
    contenttype: "application/json",
    cache:false,
    url: "../_data/gratisapps.json",
    success:function(data){
        if(data != null && data.apps != null){
            //GET PORTFOLIOITEMS FROM JSON STRING
            _nieuweApps = data.apps;
            //VISUALIZE PORTFOLIOITEMS
            vizuGratisApplicaties();
        }
    },
    error:function(xhr, result, error){
        alert(result + " " + error);
    }
});
}
function vizuGratisApplicaties(){
var content = "";
$.each(_nieuweApps, function(key, nieuweApp){
    if(nieuweApp.soort == "nieuw")
    {   var queryString = nieuweApp.title.replace(/\s+/g, '%20');
        content += '<section class="app colums cols-2 clearfix">'
        + '<a href="detailpage.html?q=' + queryString + '">'
        + '<figure><img class="app-image" src="' + nieuweApp.image + '" /></figure>'
        + '<figcaption><h4>' + nieuweApp.title + '</h4></figcaption>' 
        + '</a>'
        + '</section>';
    }
});
$('#content.gratisapps').append(content);
}
```

All these sections are floated left, with a width of 14.58333%. Does anyone have a solution for this problem/know another way to fix it?

Comment: Do you have an example link? I have a hunch the that images getting loaded in are not responsive.

Comment: the images are loaded from a local folder. So I have them on my computer..

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a little more information; how are you scaling your content? 
Could it be because the injected content is generated after the DOM is loaded initially?